# WSDL SoapClient and PHP + own Namespace

Tags: php, soap, namespaces, wsdl, request

I've tried for a while to get this SoapRequest but i'm failed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
  <soap:Body xmlns:gog="http://www.test.nms">
    <gog:GenerateRequest>
      <gog:Application>TestApp</gog:Application>
      <gog:User>TestUser</gog:User>
      <gog: RequestCreateOnly>
        <gog:Count>1</gog:Count>
        <gog:Subject>Test</gog:Subject>
      </gog: RequestCreateOnly>
    </gog:GenerateRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have to write it in PHP.
The questions are:

> how to change the Namespace?
>   how to change the soap tag?
>   thank you in advice for help!

Comment: What did you try so far? Why do you have/want to change the namespace? Which namespace do you mean, xmlns:soap or xmlns:gog?

Answer (score 0):

I often use the NuSOAP library for these kind of requests. I have included a piece of sample code below, does it help you?

```
require_once('path-to-nusoap/nusoap.php');

$client = new nusoap_client("http://www.mywebservicehere.com", 'wsdl');
$client -> setDefaultRpcParams(true);
$client -> useHTTPPersistentConnection();
$client -> soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$client -> setUseCurl(true);

$request = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <soap:Body xmlns:gog="http://www.test.nms">
                    <gog:GenerateRequest>
                        <gog:Application>TestApp</gog:Application>
                        <gog:User>TestUser</gog:User>
                        <gog: RequestCreateOnly>
                            <gog:Count>1</gog:Count>
                            <gog:Subject>Test</gog:Subject>
                        </gog: RequestCreateOnly>
                    </gog:GenerateRequest>
                </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>';

$results = $client->send($request,'http://www.actionurlhere.com');
```